# Get average date value from pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a df with product data with the following schema

```
root
 |-- Creator: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Created_datetime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Last_modified_datetime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Product_name: string (nullable = true)
```

the columns `Created_datetime` looks the following

```
+-------------------+
|   Created_datetime|
+-------------------+
|2019-10-12 17:09:18|
|2019-12-03 07:02:07|
|2020-01-16 23:10:08|
```

Now I would like to extract the average value (or the closest value to the avg existing) in the `Created_datetime` column. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you calculate the average of a `timestamp` column, it will give you the average `unix timestamp (long)` value. Cast it back to a `timestamp`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.agg(F.avg("Created_datetime").cast("timestamp").alias("avg_created_datetime")).show()
+--------------------+                                                          
|avg_created_datetime|
+--------------------+
| 2019-11-30 23:27:11|
+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would like to apply casting first to unix_timestamp by passing date format of record then apply avg agg function after second casting datetime to time format like this snippet below:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, date_format, unix_timestamp, from_unixtime

df.withColumn('Created_datetime', unix_timestamp(date_format('Created_datetime', '2019-01-01 HH:mm:ss'))).agg(from_unixtime(avg('Created_datetime'),'HH:mm:ss').alias('Created_datetime_average')).show()
```